# Implementing generic methods for a repository using Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I am using `Entity Framework 4.1` and the `repository pattern`.

I am trying to create methods that will be used throughout most scenarios.  I am trying to create a method that brings back records and sorts it according to the order criteria supplied.  It can be sorted by 1, 2 or 3 columns.  I want this to be specified.  I found the following code in the `Orchard framework`.

In the `IRepository interface` they have the following (I left out the other methods):

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
     IEnumerable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
     IEnumerable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Action<Orderable<T>> order);
}
```

The implementation for `IEnumerable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Action<Orderable<T>> order);` is:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
     public virtual IQueryable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
     {
          return Table.Where(predicate);
     }

     public virtual IQueryable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Action<Orderable<T>> order)
     {
          var orderable = new Orderable<T>(Fetch(predicate));
          order(orderable);
          return orderable.Queryable;
     }
}
```

The `Orderable class`:

```
public class Orderable<T>
{
     private IQueryable<T> _queryable;

     public Orderable(IQueryable<T> enumerable)
     {
          _queryable = enumerable;
     }

     public IQueryable<T> Queryable
     {
          get { return _queryable; }
     }

     public Orderable<T> Asc<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
     {
          _queryable = _queryable
               .OrderBy(keySelector);
          return this;
     }

     public Orderable<T> Asc<TKey1, TKey2>(Expression<Func<T, TKey1>> keySelector1,
          Expression<Func<T, TKey2>> keySelector2)
     {
          _queryable = _queryable
               .OrderBy(keySelector1)
               .OrderBy(keySelector2);
          return this;
     }

     public Orderable<T> Asc<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>(Expression<Func<T, TKey1>> keySelector1,
          Expression<Func<T, TKey2>> keySelector2,
          Expression<Func<T, TKey3>> keySelector3)
     {
          _queryable = _queryable
               .OrderBy(keySelector1)
               .OrderBy(keySelector2)
               .OrderBy(keySelector3);
          return this;
     }

     public Orderable<T> Desc<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> keySelector)
     {
          _queryable = _queryable
               .OrderByDescending(keySelector);
          return this;
     }

     public Orderable<T> Desc<TKey1, TKey2>(Expression<Func<T, TKey1>> keySelector1,
          Expression<Func<T, TKey2>> keySelector2)
     {
          _queryable = _queryable
               .OrderByDescending(keySelector1)
               .OrderByDescending(keySelector2);
          return this;
     }

     public Orderable<T> Desc<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3>(Expression<Func<T, TKey1>> keySelector1,
          Expression<Func<T, TKey2>> keySelector2,
          Expression<Func<T, TKey3>> keySelector3)
     {
          _queryable = _queryable
               .OrderByDescending(keySelector1)
               .OrderByDescending(keySelector2)
               .OrderByDescending(keySelector3);
          return this;
     }
}
```

So a way in which this can be used will be as follows:

```
var foos = _fooRepos.Fetch(
     f => f.Name == "two" || f.Name == "three",
     o => o.Asc(f => f.Name, f => f.Id)
);
```

Is this the best possible way of doing what I am trying to achieve?  I am trying to make it as simple as possible.  I would appreciate all help and if any sample code and articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure the Orchard guys have their reasons (haven't looked at the code base), but I'm just wondering what it brings to the table compared with a more 'standard' LINQ/IQueryable-based solution?

```
public interface IRepository<T>  
{  
    IQueryable<T> All(); 
}
```

usage:

```
var foos = from f in _foosRepos.All()
           where f.Name == "two" || f.Name == "three"
           orderby f.Name, f.Id;
```

or

```
var foos = _foosRepos.All()
        .Where(f => f.Name == "two" || f.Name == "three")
        .OrderBy(f => f.Name).ThenBy(f => f.Id);
```

Comment: Cautioning against IQueryable<T>: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/26/IQueryableTisTightCoupling/

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention that the items can be sorted by 1, 2 or 3 fields, you can expand on jeroenh's response, and "merge" it with the logic from Orchard:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> All();
    IQueryable<T> Sorted(Func<T, object> sort1, Func<T, object> sort2 = null, Func<T, object> sort3 = null);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        // TODO: Implement real data retrieval
        return new List<T>().AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Sorted(Func<T, object> sort1, Func<T, object> sort2 = null, Func<T, object> sort3 = null)
    {
        var list = All();

        var res = list.OrderBy(sort1);
        if (sort2 != null)
            res = res.ThenBy(sort2);
        if (sort3 != null)
            res = res.ThenBy(sort3);
        return res.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want efficient sorting (in the database), you should use `Expression<Func<>>` instead of just `Func<>`

Answer (score 1):

See also the generic repository implementation that allows you to specify order criteria in this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application